# How to change and preserve for iterating through paginator "per page" items load for aspx-page?

Tags: python, asp.net, scrapy, paginator

I'm writing crawler for this starting url: https://usa.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/search2.aspx#PNavDS=N:0&t=pTab , using now this code:

```
class IngrammicroSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ingrammicro_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['usa.ingrammicro.com']
    start_urls = [f'https://usa.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/search2.aspx#PNavDS=N:0,Nao:{str(x)}&t=pTab' for x in range(0, 912990 + 1, 10)]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 10.0})
```

And would like to navigate all pages in paginator with setting "Per page" by 100 elements, and now it loading only by 10, I've searched in network - XHR for headers and cookies and not able to find yet any settings related to this, how that can be done? I'd like to get  only 9000 pages by 100 elements, not 90000 pages by 10 elements.
I'm not talking about changing urls to something like this:

```
start_urls = [f'https://usa.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/search2.aspx#PNavDS=N:0,Nao:{str(x)}&t=pTab' for x in range(0, 900001, 100)]
```

Because it still will be getting them by 10 elements on page, i.e. 0-10, then 100-110, then 200-210 etc.

Comment: Are you using Splash or similar? I see the page uses AJAX requests underneath for pagination, if you reproduce them you can simply change the corresponding parameter of the request. Also, given the high number of requests, it might be better to use `start_requests` instead of `start_urls` and use iteration to yield each URL, instead of building the whole URL list in memory first.

Comment: The number of items per page *is* in cookie `Search` with an example value of: `"CookieExpiryDays":365,"SearchResultsPerPage":"100","SearchResultsViewMode":null,"OpenedFacets":"","CollapsedFacets":"product-vendors-facet","SearchResultsSortBy":0}`

Comment: Do not use Splash here. Splash should be used sparingly, when nothing else can be done realistically. In this case, you should be able to avoid using Splash, and reproduce the AJAX requests instead. Open the Network tab of the Developer Tools of your web browser, load the target page, and see the request it performs to fetch data in JSON format. Then reproduce the request without Splash. Changing pagination that way should be easier. You might even be able to use higher items per page than those the webpage allows.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Splash for now, cause page was complaining and refused to show me results without javascript enabled, are you sure it will load results with usual scrapy or with FormRequest.from_response()? About setting urls in `start_requests` - will do, sure.

Comment: Wow, somethow this Cookies shows for me like this: "%7B%22CookieExpiryDays%22%3A365%2C%22SearchResultsPerPage%22%3A%2210%22%2C%22SearchResultsViewMode%22%3Anull%2C%22OpenedFacets%22%3A%"
and I can't get them normally with Chrome Developer Tools( What I should use instead? Btw, how to set them with scrapy-splash?

Comment: What if when I disabling javascript server redirects and says to me: https://i.imgur.com/W6wYFlY.png - if I will set all those "aspx" and cookies field it will give normal result?

Comment: How to set cookies? I tried this and getting now 0 results:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 5.0, 'images': 0}, cookies={
                "Search": '{"CookieExpiryDays":365,"SearchResultsPerPage":"100","SearchResultsViewMode":null,"OpenedFacets":"","CollapsedFacets":"","SearchResultsSortBy":0}'})

Comment: Also tried this, also getting 0 results:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 5.0, 'images': 0}, cookies={
                "Search": '%7B%22CookieExpiryDays%22%3A365%2C%22SearchResultsPerPage%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22SearchResultsViewMode%22%3Anull%2C%22OpenedFacets%22%3A%22%22%2C%22CollapsedFacets%22%3A%22%22%2C%22SearchResultsSortBy%22%3A0%7D '})

Comment: Please, re-read my previous comment. I am telling you that the site is using AJAX. That means that the page HTML does not contain the data, but it performs a second asynchronous request using JavaScript that fetches the data. Instead of loading the original webpage from Scrapy, you can perform a request for that second, asynchronous request from Scrapy.

Comment: Find the request to `https://usa.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/SearchService.svc/Search` in the Network tab of the Developer Tools of your web browser, and try to perform a similar request from Scrapy and extract the desired data from there.

Answer (score 0):

Change as,

```
start_urls = [f'https://usa.ingrammicro.com/_layouts/CommerceServer/IM/search2.aspx#PNavDS=N:0,Nao:{str(x)}&t=pTab' for x in range(0, 900001, 100)]
```

Comment: It will not help, because it still will be getting them by 10 elements on page, i.e. 0-10, then 100-110, then 200-210 etc.